# Formatting issue with a Kendo Timepicker

Tags: jquery, sql, asp.net-mvc

I have a strongly typed view that I am passing a model into.  However, I'm having a formatting issue with a time picker.  I retrieve the data from the database (SQL Management Server 2008), and the column I'm pulling from in the db is a "time" column and the time is stored in the db correctly, storing just the time.  When I pull the data and load it into my time picker, I get the correct time but I'm also getting 1/1/1753.  I have data annotations in the model specifying the data type as time and in the view, I have a jquery function formatting the time as "hh:mm:ss tt" so I'm kind of lost as to why the formatting isn't working.  Here are some code snippets:

From the view:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.TimeIn, new { id = "timeIn" })
```

JQuery function inside view:

```
$("#timeIn").kendoTimePicker({
    format: "hh:mm:ss tt"
});
```

Model:

```
[Display(Name = "Time In")]
[Required]
[DataType(DataType.Time)]
[DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode=true, DataFormatString = "{0:hh:mm:ss tt}")]
public DateTime TimeIn { get; set; }
```

Thank you in advance,
Shaun

Comment: Did you test in your controller how the data is pulled from the database? It's possible that the format gets messed up due to the data annotation. In that case, formating a "bad" value withing your JavaScript would not produce anything useful.

Comment: Hello Andrei, when I debugged the controller it's pulling in the time and year.  I seemed to have remedied this.  Since this page is pulling I switched

Comment: Oops, sorry, accidently hit something.  I switched out the textboxfor for a @Html.Kendo().TimePickerFor(m => m.timeIn) and that did the trick.  Not exactly sure why the previous method wasn't working, unless I was trying to format the data after it was already populated in the control when the page rendered.